# When does "X is NP-complete" imply "#X is #P-complete"?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, counting-complexity

Let $X$ denote a (decision) problem in NP and let #$X$ denote its counting version.

Under what conditions is it known that "X is NP-complete" $\implies$ "#X is #P-complete"?

Of course the existence of a parsimonious reduction is one such condition, but this is obvious and the only such condition of which I am aware.  The ultimate goal would be to show that no condition is needed.

Formally speaking, one should start with the counting problem #$X$ defined by a function $f : \{0,1\}^* \to \mathbb{N}$ and then define the decision problem $X$ on an input string $s$ as $f(s) \ne 0$?

Comment: Are you looking for something more than "X is NP-complete under parsimonious reductions"?

Comment: @Joshua is that a necessary condition?

Comment: @usul: No. If we drop the assumption that X is NP-complete, then bipartite matching is in P (so definitely not parsimoniously NP-complete assuming $P \neq NP$) but its counting version is #P-complete. However, if we really want X NP-complete, then off the top of my head I don't know of a problem X such that: 1) X is NP-complete, 2) X is *not* NP-complete under parsimonious reductions, and 3) #X is #P-complete. But I haven't really thought about it.

Comment: But is there a problem that negates this ? i.e X is NP-complete and #X is not #P-complete ?

Comment: @SureshVenkat: If #X can be solved in polynomial time, then by checking the number of solutions is zero or more, we can determine the existence of a solution in polynomial time. Am I missing something? Probably, I didn't get a point of this question.

Comment: @YoshioOkamoto: that proves that #X ∈ **#P** implies that X ∈ **NP**. It's in the wrong direction and misses the problem of completeness. What we're looking at essentially is what additional requirements are needed in order for the existence of a many-to-one reduction for decision problems in **NP** (for arbitrary decision problems, or from an **NP**-complete problem) entails the existence of a efficient counting reduction for problems in **#P** (for arbitrary counting problems, or from a **#P**-complete problem).

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap: Ah, I see. Thank you very much.

Comment: The question is phrased a little imprecisely, since there is no unique counting version for a given decision problem.

Comment: @ColinMcQuillan It could be stated in reverse.  Start with a counting problem and define a decision problem from it asking if the output is nonzero.

Comment: @Tayfun, that makes it clear that the counting version is in #P, but I don't see a straightforward reason that it is #P-complete (except the case of parsimonious reductions).

Comment: A result of this type "X is NP-complete implies #X is #P-complete" is proved for satisfiability problems.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The most recent paper on this question seems to be:

Noam Livne, *A note on #P-completeness of NP-witnessing relations*, 
Information Processing Letters, Volume 109, Issue 5, 15 February 2009, Pages 259–261
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020019008003141

which gives some sufficient conditions.

Interestingly the introduction states "To date, all known NP complete sets have a defining relation which is #P complete", so the answer to Suresh's comment is "no examples are known".

Answer (score 7):

[Fischer, Sophie, Lane Hemaspaandra, and Leen Torenvliet. "Witness-isomorphic reductions and local search." LECTURE NOTES IN PURE AND APPLIED MATHEMATICS (1997): 207-224.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.49.7279)

At the beginning of section 3.5, they ask the following question " In
particular, are there NP-complete sets that with respect to some witness
scheme are not #P -complete?"

And then they prove in Theorem 3.1 that "If there is a NP -complete set L that with respect to some witnessing relation R$_L$ is not #P-complete, then ${\bf P} $ $\not =$ ${\bf P^{\bf \#P}}$".